# How to solve java.util.NoSuchElementException: for HashMaps and ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist, graph, hashmap

Hi so I keep on having the `java.util.NoSuchElementException` for my code in two instances

In the first instance:
it says

1)

> Java.util.NoSuchElementException null in java.util.ArrayList$ltr

line. I'm confused do I need an iterator for both the Hashmap values and for the Arraylist MaxCoPurchase as well? I'm just very confused.

2) The second instant when the

> Java.util.NoSuchElementException comes up with the following line:
>   null in (Java.util.HashMap$HashIterator)

I'm confused once again.
If anyone could help me and have some suggestions or even code fixes that would be great

Answer (score 0):

- In the first case, the `maxCoPurchase` collection is clearly empty, probably the map as well.
- In the second case, the `maxMap` is clearly empty. This is poor code which you should rewrite. When you save the maximum value you should also somehow save its key directly, instead of having to search for it. Or at least break out of the loop when you've found it.
- In both cases, instead of iterating the key set and calling `get()` to get the associated value, you should iterate the entry set, which gives you the key and the value at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when the collection is empty (in your case) or it does not contain the next value(especially when you are iterating it).

First case: A proper null check for the Arraylist "maxCoPurchase" will avoid this exception.
Second case: A proper null check for the HashMap "maxMap" will avoid this exception.

I hope this helps.